# Java - Interact with website to update information

Tags: java, http, url, interaction

So I got this situation and I may have 2 different routes to take.  The thing is I have to update some information I generate, already formatted and parsed and ready to be displayed.  Now I don't know how to input this txt file (or giant string) into the site.  One way to do it is to find a way for Java to interact with the page, paste the info in the text area and Save/Submit the update.  The other way is to edit the page file itself inserting the giant string in the place it's supposed to go.  I've been researching about HTTP Forms, but most are used with third party libraries.  But I have no idea how to do either route.  Ive been checking these sites, and other, but I think some are too complex or need external libraries like Selenium, and I really have no experience using URLConnection class.  Thanks for the help!

--I don't have control of the server, I can simply access it, so I was thinking that the first idea would be more practical...

http://kspace.in/blog/2008/05/30/submit-html-form-using-java/

http://www.devcomments.com/q450155/How-to-have-Java-application-interact-with-website

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HTTP Post:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html

```
try {
    // Construct data
    String data = URLEncoder.encode("key1", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");
    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("key2", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value2", "UTF-8");

    // Send data
    URL url = new URL("http://hostname:80/cgi");
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.write(data);
    wr.flush();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        // Process line...
    }
    wr.close();
    rd.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: ok, but this writes the whole file with the simple string I have, doesn't it?  How could I only post the generated info in a particular section of the whole HTML?  I thought of using the tag forms to know exactly where it should go...

Comment: Well right now, the `data` object holds some text. You would have to do some processing of your HTML to extract the strings you want to send to the website, and post them. You'll have to look at the page with the textbox to see what url it's posting to.

Comment: Hmm, thanks all for the help, Ill try to modify this out to my needs then

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a framework designed for automated testing, such as [Selenium/WebDriver](http://seleniumhq.org/) or [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/). Yes, you're not actually running tests, but they work well for this kind of automation.

Comment: If I had votes left today I would totally give a +1 for this. If what you need is just a one time thing, this is an excellent idea. If it's going to be long term, of course, you might want to consider the more technical solution like I have above. But for something simple, I'd really consider this avenue!

Comment: yeah, I did consider it, but I decided to implement it in python lol thanks for the help!